# Actionscript 2.0 How can I bring a layer button to the front on rollover in Flash?

Tags: flash, animation, navigation, actionscript-2, layer

Okay, I have 4 layers. actions, buttons, circle, and background. I have three buttons on the buttons layer that are each supposed to fill the circle shown in the circle layer, on rollover. The issue that I am having is that when I hover over a button, the rollover animation is partially covered by one of the other buttons or both, dependent upon where they are sitting in the arrangement. I need to somehow bring whichever one is being rolled over to move to the front or to a new layer.
[image]

As far as coding... I completely removed all of my code. It was :

```
on(rollOver)
{
    this.swapDepths(1000);
}
```

on each button

Comment: You can have use Depthmanager to achieve this.Use swapDepths.

Comment: Didn't even know there was such a thing. I've been googling it for a couple hours and the "best answer" I can find is at:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002324.html

But I have no idea where to put the coding. Would I apply this to the main timeline?

Comment: It would be easy to give suggestions if you attach the screenshot and the code you are using.

Comment: Added some detail. Hopefully that will make things easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
on(rollOver)
{
    this.swapDepths(_root.getNextHighestDepth());
}
```

or in the maintimeline

```
button1.onRollOver = function(){
this.swapDepths(_root.getNextHighestDepth());
}

button2.onRollOver = function(){
this.swapDepths(_root.getNextHighestDepth());
}

button3.onRollOver = function(){
this.swapDepths(_root.getNextHighestDepth());
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes and no. It works for the first rollover, but then when I go to rollOver one of the others, the previous rolled one is on top.